# Building Mplayer from sources in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mplayer

I've encountered a problem trying to build Mplayer from sources (svn version). I run 'configure' script with no parameters. It indicates no problems. FFmpeg compiles fine, but the last stage, that is building mplayer, fails:

```
ffmpeg/libavcodec/h263dec.o: In function `ff_h263_decode_frame':
h263dec.c:(.text+0xddb): undefined reference to `ff_h263_find_frame_end'
h263dec.c:(.text+0xfa0): undefined reference to `ff_mpeg4_find_frame_end'
ffmpeg/libavcodec/mlpdec.o: In function `read_access_unit':
mlpdec.c:(.text+0x128a): undefined reference to `ff_mlp_read_major_sync'
ffmpeg/libavcodec/ac3dec_fixed.o: In function `ac3_decode_frame':
ac3dec_fixed.c:(.text+0x73a3): undefined reference to `ff_ac3_parse_header'
ac3dec_fixed.c:(.text+0x7d4f): undefined reference to `ff_ac3_parse_header'
ffmpeg/libavcodec/ac3dec_float.o: In function `ac3_decode_frame':
ac3dec_float.c:(.text+0x687f): undefined reference to `ff_ac3_parse_header'
ac3dec_float.c:(.text+0x727b): undefined reference to `ff_ac3_parse_header'
ffmpeg/libavcodec/eac3_core_bsf.o: In function `eac3_core_filter':
eac3_core_bsf.c:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `ff_ac3_parse_header'
ffmpeg/libavcodec/eac3_core_bsf.o:eac3_core_bsf.c:(.text+0x174): more undefined references to `ff_ac3_parse_header' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:747: recipe for target 'mplayer' failed
make: *** [mplayer] Error 1
```

The above resulted from:

```
cc -o mplayer command.o m_property.o mixer.o mp_fifo.o mplayer.o parser-mpcmd.o pnm_loader.o input/input.o libao2/ao_mpegpes.o libao2/ao_null.o libao2/ao_pcm.o libao2/audio_out.o libvo/aspect.o libvo/geometry.o libvo/video_out.o libvo/vo_mpegpes.o libvo/vo_null.o sub/spuenc.o libvo/vo_aa.o libao2/ao_alsa.o input/appleir.o libvo/vo_caca.o libvo/vo_dga.o libvo/vo_directfb2.o libvo/vo_dfbmga.o libvo/vo_fbdev.o libvo/vo_fbdev2.o libvo/vo_png.o libvo/vo_gif89a.o libvo/gl_common.o libvo/vo_gl.o libvo/csputils.o libvo/sdl_common.o libvo/x11_common.o libvo/vo_gl_tiled.o libao2/ao_jack.o libvo/vo_jpeg.o input/lirc.o libvo/vo_matrixview.o libvo/matrixview.o libvo/vo_md5sum.o libvo/vo_mng.o libao2/ao_nas.o udp_sync.o libao2/ao_openal.o libao2/ao_oss.o libvo/vo_pnm.o libao2/ao_pulse.o libao2/ao_sdl.o libvo/vo_sdl.o libvo/vo_tga.o libvo/vo_v4l2.o libao2/ao_v4l2.o libvo/vo_vdpau.o libvo/vo_cvidix.o libvo/vosub_vidix.o vidix/vidix.o vidix/drivers.o vidix/dha.o vidix/mtrr.o vidix/pci.o vidix/pci_names.o vidix/pci_dev_ids.o vidix/cyberblade_vid.o vidix/mach64_vid.o vidix/mga_vid.o vidix/mga_crtc2_vid.o vidix/nvidia_vid.o vidix/pm2_vid.o vidix/pm3_vid.o vidix/radeon_vid.o vidix/rage128_vid.o vidix/s3_vid.o vidix/sis_vid.o vidix/sis_bridge.o vidix/unichrome_vid.o libvo/vo_x11.o libvo/vo_xover.o libvo/vo_xv.o libvo/vo_xvidix.o libvo/vo_yuv4mpeg.o asxparser.o bstr.o codec-cfg.o cpudetect.o edl.o fmt-conversion.o m_config.o m_option.o m_struct.o mp_msg.o mp_strings.o mpcommon.o parser-cfg.o path.o playtree.o playtreeparser.o subopt-helper.o libaf/af.o libaf/af_center.o libaf/af_channels.o libaf/af_comp.o libaf/af_delay.o libaf/af_dummy.o libaf/af_equalizer.o libaf/af_extrastereo.o libaf/af_format.o libaf/af_gate.o libaf/af_hrtf.o libaf/af_karaoke.o libaf/af_pan.o libaf/af_resample.o libaf/af_scaletempo.o libaf/af_sinesuppress.o libaf/af_stats.o libaf/af_sub.o libaf/af_surround.o libaf/af_sweep.o libaf/af_tools.o libaf/af_volnorm.o libaf/af_volume.o libaf/filter.o libaf/format.o libaf/reorder_ch.o libaf/window.o libmpcodecs/ad.o libmpcodecs/ad_alaw.o libmpcodecs/ad_dvdpcm.o libmpcodecs/ad_hwac3.o libmpcodecs/ad_hwmpa.o libmpcodecs/ad_pcm.o libmpcodecs/dec_audio.o libmpcodecs/dec_teletext.o libmpcodecs/dec_video.o libmpcodecs/img_format.o libmpcodecs/mp_image.o libmpcodecs/pullup.o libmpcodecs/vd.o libmpcodecs/vd_hmblck.o libmpcodecs/vd_lzo.o libmpcodecs/vd_mpegpes.o libmpcodecs/vd_mtga.o libmpcodecs/vd_null.o libmpcodecs/vd_raw.o libmpcodecs/vd_sgi.o libmpcodecs/vd_black.o libmpcodecs/vf.o libmpcodecs/vf_1bpp.o libmpcodecs/vf_2xsai.o libmpcodecs/vf_blackframe.o libmpcodecs/vf_boxblur.o libmpcodecs/vf_crop.o libmpcodecs/vf_cropdetect.o libmpcodecs/vf_decimate.o libmpcodecs/vf_delogo.o libmpcodecs/vf_denoise3d.o libmpcodecs/vf_detc.o libmpcodecs/vf_dint.o libmpcodecs/vf_divtc.o libmpcodecs/vf_down3dright.o libmpcodecs/vf_dsize.o libmpcodecs/vf_dvbscale.o libmpcodecs/vf_eq.o libmpcodecs/vf_eq2.o libmpcodecs/vf_expand.o libmpcodecs/vf_field.o libmpcodecs/vf_fil.o libmpcodecs/vf_filmdint.o libmpcodecs/vf_fixpts.o libmpcodecs/vf_flip.o libmpcodecs/vf_format.o libmpcodecs/vf_framestep.o libmpcodecs/vf_gradfun.o libmpcodecs/vf_halfpack.o libmpcodecs/vf_harddup.o libmpcodecs/vf_hqdn3d.o libmpcodecs/vf_hue.o libmpcodecs/vf_il.o libmpcodecs/vf_ilpack.o libmpcodecs/vf_ivtc.o libmpcodecs/vf_kerndeint.o libmpcodecs/vf_mirror.o libmpcodecs/vf_noformat.o libmpcodecs/vf_noise.o libmpcodecs/vf_ow.o libmpcodecs/vf_palette.o libmpcodecs/vf_perspective.o libmpcodecs/vf_phase.o libmpcodecs/vf_pp7.o libmpcodecs/vf_pullup.o libmpcodecs/vf_rectangle.o libmpcodecs/vf_remove_logo.o libmpcodecs/vf_rgbtest.o libmpcodecs/vf_rotate.o libmpcodecs/vf_sab.o libmpcodecs/vf_scale.o libmpcodecs/vf_smartblur.o libmpcodecs/vf_softpulldown.o libmpcodecs/vf_stereo3d.o libmpcodecs/vf_softskip.o libmpcodecs/vf_swapuv.o libmpcodecs/vf_telecine.o libmpcodecs/vf_test.o libmpcodecs/vf_tfields.o libmpcodecs/vf_tile.o libmpcodecs/vf_tinterlace.o libmpcodecs/vf_unsharp.o libmpcodecs/vf_vo.o libmpcodecs/vf_yadif.o libmpcodecs/vf_yuvcsp.o libmpcodecs/vf_yvu9.o libmpdemux/aac_hdr.o libmpdemux/asfheader.o libmpdemux/aviheader.o libmpdemux/aviprint.o libmpdemux/demuxer.o libmpdemux/demux_aac.o libmpdemux/demux_asf.o libmpdemux/demux_audio.o libmpdemux/demux_avi.o libmpdemux/demux_demuxers.o libmpdemux/demux_film.o libmpdemux/demux_fli.o libmpdemux/demux_lmlm4.o libmpdemux/demux_mf.o libmpdemux/demux_mkv.o libmpdemux/demux_mov.o libmpdemux/demux_mpg.o libmpdemux/demux_nsv.o libmpdemux/demux_pva.o libmpdemux/demux_rawaudio.o libmpdemux/demux_rawvideo.o libmpdemux/demux_realaud.o libmpdemux/demux_real.o libmpdemux/demux_roq.o libmpdemux/demux_smjpeg.o libmpdemux/demux_ts.o libmpdemux/demux_ty.o libmpdemux/demux_ty_osd.o libmpdemux/demux_viv.o libmpdemux/demux_vqf.o libmpdemux/demux_y4m.o libmpdemux/ebml.o libmpdemux/extension.o libmpdemux/mf.o libmpdemux/mp3_hdr.o libmpdemux/mp_taglists.o libmpdemux/mpeg_hdr.o libmpdemux/mpeg_packetizer.o libmpdemux/parse_es.o libmpdemux/parse_mp4.o libmpdemux/video.o libmpdemux/yuv4mpeg.o libmpdemux/yuv4mpeg_ratio.o osdep/getch2.o osdep/timer-linux.o stream/open.o stream/stream.o stream/stream_bd.o stream/stream_cue.o stream/stream_file.o stream/stream_mf.o stream/stream_null.o stream/url.o sub/eosd.o sub/find_sub.o sub/osd.o sub/spudec.o sub/sub.o sub/sub_cc.o sub/subreader.o sub/vobsub.o stream/ai_alsa.o stream/ai_oss.o sub/font_load.o stream/stream_cdda.o stream/cdinfo.o stream/stream_cddb.o stream/dvb_tune.o stream/stream_dvb.o stream/stream_dvdnav.o stream/stream_dvd.o stream/stream_dvd_common.o libmpcodecs/ad_faad.o libvo/aclib.o av_helpers.o av_opts.o libaf/af_lavcac3enc.o libaf/af_lavcresample.o libmpcodecs/ad_ffmpeg.o libmpcodecs/ad_spdif.o libmpcodecs/vd_ffmpeg.o libmpcodecs/vf_geq.o libmpcodecs/vf_lavc.o libmpcodecs/vf_lavcdeint.o libmpcodecs/vf_screenshot.o libmpdemux/demux_lavf.o stream/stream_ffmpeg.o sub/av_sub.o libmpcodecs/vf_fspp.o libmpcodecs/vf_qp.o libmpcodecs/vf_spp.o libmpcodecs/vf_uspp.o sub/font_load_ft.o stream/stream_ftp.o libmpdemux/demux_gif.o libmpcodecs/vf_bmovl.o libaf/af_export.o osdep/mmap_anon.o libmpcodecs/vd_ijpg.o libaf/af_ladspa.o libmpcodecs/ad_liba52.o libmpcodecs/vf_ass.o sub/ass_mp.o sub/subassconvert.o stream/stream_bluray.o libaf/af_bs2b.o libmpcodecs/ad_libdca.o libmpcodecs/ad_libdv.o libmpcodecs/vd_libdv.o libmpdemux/demux_rawdv.o libmpcodecs/ad_libmad.o libmpcodecs/vd_libmpeg2.o stream/stream_smb.o libmpcodecs/vd_theora.o libmpdemux/demux_mng.o libmpcodecs/ad_mpg123.o stream/stream_rtsp.o stream/freesdp/common.o stream/freesdp/errorlist.o stream/freesdp/parser.o stream/librtsp/rtsp.o stream/librtsp/rtsp_rtp.o stream/librtsp/rtsp_session.o stream/stream_netstream.o stream/asf_mmst_streaming.o stream/asf_streaming.o stream/cookies.o stream/http.o stream/network.o stream/pnm.o stream/rtp.o stream/udp.o stream/tcp.o stream/stream_rtp.o stream/stream_udp.o stream/realrtsp/asmrp.o stream/realrtsp/real.o stream/realrtsp/rmff.o stream/realrtsp/sdpplin.o stream/realrtsp/xbuffer.o libmpcodecs/vd_mpng.o libmpcodecs/vf_pp.o stream/stream_pvr.o libmpcodecs/ad_realaud.o libmpcodecs/vd_realvid.o libmpcodecs/ad_speex.o stream/cache2.o stream/frequencies.o stream/stream_tv.o stream/tv.o stream/tvi_dummy.o stream/tvi_v4l2.o stream/audio_in.o sub/unrar_exec.o stream/stream_vcd.o libmpcodecs/ad_libvorbis.o libmpdemux/demux_ogg.o stream/stream_vstream.o libmpcodecs/vd_xanim.o libmpcodecs/vd_xvid4.o osdep/shmem.o ffmpeg/libpostproc/libpostproc.a ffmpeg/libavfilter/libavfilter.a ffmpeg/libavformat/libavformat.a ffmpeg/libavcodec/libavcodec.a ffmpeg/libswscale/libswscale.a ffmpeg/libswresample/libswresample.a ffmpeg/libavutil/libavutil.a -Wl,--version-script,binary.ver -Wl,-z,noexecstack  -ffast-math -fpie -pie   -lncurses -lrt -lgnutls -lsmbclient -lpng -lz -lmng -lz -ljpeg -lgif -lasound -ldl -lpthread -lbluray -ldvdread -lcdio_cdda -lcdio -lcdio_paranoia  -lfreetype -lfontconfig  -lfribidi -lass -lenca -lz -llzo2 -lmad -logg -lvorbisidec -lspeex -lgsm -ltheoradec -logg -lmpg123 -la52 -lmpeg2 -ldca -lfaad -lopus -lbs2b -lrtmp -ldv -lcrystalhd -lxvidcore -lvstream-client -lpthread -ldl -rdynamic -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ldvdnav -lpthread -lm   -ldirectfb -lXext -lX11 -lpthread -lXss -lXv -lvdpau -lXinerama -lXxf86vm -lXxf86dga -laa -lcaca -lSDL -lGL -ldl -laudio -lXt -lpulse -ljack -lopenal -lx264 -lpthread -lmp3lame -llirc_client
```

Any hints or ideas? I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

ac3_parser.c, h263_parser.c in ffmpeg/libavcodec failed to compile, perhaps others.  Try updating the svn version.  If that doesn't work try workaround:

```
cd ffmpeg/libavcodec

cc -I../.. -I..  -c -o ac3_parser.o ac3_parser.c

ar rT libavcodec.a ac3_parser.o
```

## repeat as necessary for what is missing...

```
cd -

make all
```

Comment: I still don't know what was the cause, but when I downloaded the svn version again some time later (a month or so) without any further action from my side, the building went just fine.